# How to authenticate only once with http auth and two domains in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-authentication

I have a site that requires 2 domains: one for dynamic and the other for static content.

In the staging environment I need it to ask for user and password as I don't want random people or bots having access to that. I have used http_auth for that.

The problem is that when you try to access, it asks for your credentials twice: once for each domain. Which is annoying.

How can I avoid that?